# Firebase get guests in date range

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app for hotel management using vue, vuex and firestore. I can't find a solution for querying guests that are in a date range, for example that are now checked in but came yesterday. I can't check .where("arrival", <=, today) and .where("departure", >= today), how can I get the list of current guests than? I have checked all the documentation but I'm still in the same place after 5 days.....

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDWyx.jpg)

This is what I tried

```js
getGuestsByRoom() {
        const startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setHours(14, 0, 0, 0);
        db.collection("guests")
          .where("room", "==", this.room)
          .where("arrival", "<=", startDate)
          .where("departure", ">=", endDate)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              console.log(doc.id);
              this.guests.push(doc.data());
            });
          });
      },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code and a screenshot of your Firestore structure will help to.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Edited question with database and code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by checking the docs by an if statemant:

```js
//current guests in room
      getGuestsByRoom() {
        db.collection("guests")
          .where("room", "==", this.room)

          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              let data = doc.data();

              const startDate = new Date();
              startDate.setHours(14, 0, 0, 0);
              console.log("start date: ", startDate);
              
              if (
                data.dates.arrival.toDate() <= startDate &&
                data.dates.departure.toDate() >= startDate
              ) {
                this.guests.push(doc.data());
                console.log("arrival: ", data.dates.arrival.toDate());
              } else {
                console.log("no guests in room");
              }
            });
          });
      },
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, maybe you could add a field "checked-in: true or false" and than run a cloud function in firestore to populate this field by checking the arrival and departure data. Than you could just have .where("room", "==", room) and a second .where("checked-in", "==", true).